# Add Custom Admin Button in component - Joomla4

Tags: joomla-4

I've created many custom buttons in my components for Joomla! 3 but I hit a stubbling block creating one in J4.
In my View file I have

```
$toolbar = Toolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
```

and then I've tried

```
$toolbar->custom('processData', Text::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_PROCESS_DATA'), 'mycontroller.processData');
$toolbar->CustomButton('processData', Text::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_PROCESS_DATA'), 'mycontroller.processData');
```

And I've tried

```
\Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\Button\CustomButton::renderButton('processData', Text::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_PROCESS_DATA'), 'mycontroller.processData');
```

Any advice/guidance appreciated.  Cheers.

Comment: I must have had a brain fade yesterday, used the old J3 code and it works a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a fresh mind this morning, I thought I'd try the old J3 way using the ToolbarHelper and problem solved.

```
ToolbarHelper::custom('mycontroller.processData', 'process.png', 'process_f2.png', 'COM_MYCOMPONENT_PROCESS_DATA', false);
```

Later Edit:
I've been trying to take more notice of the @deprecated 5.0 flags so thanks again @Carlitorweb. So it's only the second icon (iconOver) param is deprecated in 5.0.
Because I simply wanted a duplicate button option, I actually used the save2copy variety and because I'm using a childToolbar within a dropdown, I've ended up with:

```
$dropdown = $toolbar->dropdownButton('status-group')
    ->text('JTOOLBAR_CHANGE_STATUS')
    ->toggleSplit(false)
    ->icon('fas fa-ellipsis-h')
    ->buttonClass('btn btn-action')
    ->listCheck(true);

$childBar = $dropdown->getChildToolbar();
$childBar->save2copy('events.duplicate', 'Duplicate')->listCheck(true);
```

And then there's the standardButton too which I'm using to show the number of records:

```
$nRecords = $this->pagination->total;
$toolbar->standardButton('nrecords')
    ->icon('fa fa-info-circle')
    ->text($nRecords . ' Records')
    ->task('')
    ->onclick('return false')
    ->listCheck(false);
```

This works well and hope it might help others.

Comment: Is like this. The 3 param will deprecated at v5.0. But for more info he can check directly the function at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/78e61fbe96aa4f7c8670d61e53dddce273fdf251/libraries/src/Toolbar/ToolbarHelper.php#L102